# Is there any tool that can create a logic circuit equivalent to some Verilog code?

Tags: verilog, logic-gates, synthesis

For the purpose of learning, I would like to know if there is any tool (free or commercial) that can synthesize some Verilog code and produce the equivalent logic circuit.

Example :

```
assign z = (a & b) | c;
```

[image]

I am not interested how to see how it is implemented in a FPGA (which AFAIK is specific for each model and usually use LUT's and blocks interconnected together) but rather a logic circuit which is equivalent of some Verilog code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just about any FPGA/PLD tool should be able to do that.
In the somewhat obsolete Xilinx ISE Project Navigator that I currently have open the first item under Synthesize is "View RTL schematic". Selecting this brings up a diagram of the created logic.

Every synthesis tool I've used has had a similar option somewhere. As with any auto-generated schematic the results are never very neat but they are there.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with EDA Playground ?

Comment: Now you are just being lazy. I've never heard of EDA Playground and I found this http://eda-playground.readthedocs.io/en/latest/yosys-circuit-diagrams.html in about 30 seconds. Just select Yosys in the synthesis section of the tools box and click the show diagram option.

Comment: To be honest, before asking the OP I checked in EDA playground if there was a way to do this. If selected "Yosys", tried the "Download" checkbox but totally missed the "Show diagram" one. It thought that it was required to use an external tool to view the diagram (from the downloaded files). Writing a question on EESE usually take time so I usually try to find a way by myself before going here. I don't understand the downvotes btw. Maybe this website is not for beginners.

Comment: I'm guessing someone gave the downvote for asking a question without sufficient research or attempting to answer the question yourself first. That you were using a tool that had an option to do what you wanted is a sign of that. Personally I'd still consider this a useful question for others and we can all miss the obvious at times.

Answer (score 0):

Digital Logic Simulators—

DigitalJS Online   - http://digitaljs.tilk.eu/    Verilog to Circuit

Visualizing Verilog Simulation | Hackaday

FPGA | Hackaday

A Breadboard In A Browser | Hackaday

Comment: shyed2001 - Hi, (a) Your answer is being flagged as suspected spam, probably for several reasons e.g. you are linking to a specific tool on a 6+ year old question, as if you are trying to promote that tool. Do you have any affiliation / connection with that tool? Why are you mentioning *that* one? (b) Although new users have a limited ability to add links, I think the limit is more than one. Why are you not linking to any of (what looks like) the 3 other points in your answer? Please explain fully in a comment below. || As you're new here, please see the main site rules in the [tour] & [help].